# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ [\ln(x+1)]^{10}-\ln(x^{10}+1)}{x^{11}}$

Tags: limits

Calculate the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \ln^{10}(x+1)-\ln(x^{10}+1)}{x^{11}}.$$

Options:

a) $\; 5$

b) $\; 0$

c) $\; -5$

d) $\; 10$

e) $\; -10$

Note: It's high school level (no series)

I have tried with L'Hôpital's rule and I got $-10/11$.

Here:
[image]

Comment: Your post is unreadable, please improve.

Comment: Something off with your working, one of the options is correct.

Comment: Substituting $y=x^{11}$, this limit turns into a derivative, but getting that derivative involves computing another not-so-nice limit...$$\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\ln^{10}\left(y^{1/11}+1\right)-\ln\left(y^{10/11}+1\right)}{y} = \frac{d}{dy} \left[\ln^{10}\left(y^{1/11}+1\right)-\ln\left(y^{10/11}+1\right)\right] \bigg|_{y=0}\\= \frac{10}{11} \lim_{y\to0} \left(\frac{\ln^9\left(y^{1/11}+1\right)}{y^{10/11} \left(y^{1/11}+1\right)} - \frac1{y^{1/11} \left(y^{10/11}+1\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left[\ln(x+1)\right]^{10} - \ln(x^{10} + 1)}{x^{11}} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left(x -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \dotsb\right)^{10} - \left(x^{10} - \frac{x^{20}}{2} + \dotsb\right)}{x^{11}} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(x^{10} - 5x^{11} + \dotsb\right) - \left(x^{10} - \frac{x^{20}}{2} + \dotsb\right)}{x^{11}} \\
&=-5\\
\end{align*}

[Taylor Series Expansion of $\ln(1+\theta) \text{ provided } \theta \text{ is small}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asUdz.png)

Comment: How did you get $-5x^{11}$?. I get that will be simplified with the nominator and other powers will be $0$, but how -5$x^{11}$.

Comment: @AlexandruȚECU $$\left(x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac {x^3}3 \dots \right)^{10} = \left(x^{10} -10 \times x^9\times \frac{x^{2}}2 \dots \text{higher powers of $x$}\right)$$

Comment: To be honest, don't think of this as a problem of expansion. Just try to imagine what the least power terms would be if you expanded the functions into their series expansions. In fact, you can tell the answer without doing any expansion or simple mental calculation.
To answer your question, "Why did you get the wrong answer?" [Bob Dobbs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738770/calculate-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-lnx110-lnx101x11/4739078#4739078)

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\left(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\right)$$
is true when both  $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist. I think your solution went wrong when you tried this trick.

Considering the Maclaurin series
$\ln^{10}(x+1)=x^{10}-5x^{11}+h.o.t$
and
$\ln(x^{10}+1)=x^{10}-\frac12 x^{20}+h.o.t$
we can easily show that the limit is $-5$ that is the answer is C. Ercanayan explained this method more. It is not easy to suggest another method. Maybe L'Hospital rule together with induction.

Let $a_n=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln^n(x+1)-x^{n}}{x^{n+1}}$. Claim: $a_n=-\frac n2$. Applying L'Hospital rule to $a_n$, we find
$$a_n=\frac{n}{n+1}(a_{n-1}-1).$$
By induction our claim follows. Note that $a_1=-\frac12.$

Comment: Yes, It makes sense, but could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

We have, $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ [\ln(x+1)]^{10}-\ln(x^{10}+1)}{x^{11}}$$

As L falls under the $\frac{0}{0}$ category, one can proceed with L'Hospital rule right from the start, however here's an alternate approach,

Rewriting L,
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ [\ln(x+1)]^{10}-\ln(x^{10}+1)+x^{10}-x^{10}}{x^{11}}$$

$$L=(-1)\left[\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x^{10})-x^{10}}{x^{11}}+\frac{x^{10}-(\log(1+x))^{10}}{x^{11}}\right]$$

Using Taylor series/Mclaurin expansion (or L'Hospital as well)

$$log_e(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}$$ $$L=-5$$

> Extra(1) - you can find the below mentioned generalized/ standard form
> pretty much anywhere;  $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
>  {\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

---

> Extra(2) - There also exists a (well known) generalized result for your problem(works for $n>1)$
>
> $$\left[\lim_{x \to 0}
>  \frac{\ln^n{(1+x)}-\ln{(1+x^n)}}{x^{n+1}}\right]=\frac{-n}{2}$$